# Kafka scala Consumer code - to print consumed records

Tags: scala, kafka-consumer-api

As i am creating simple kafka consumer as below by using url :https://gist.github.com/akhil/6dfda8a04e33eff91a20 .

In that link, to print the consumed record, used a word "asScala" , that is not identified. and kindly , tell me, how to iterate the return type : ConsumerRecord[String,String] , which is poll() method's return type.

```js
import java.util
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerRecords, KafkaConsumer}

 
object KafkaConsumerEx extends App {

  val topic_name = "newtopic55"
  val consumer_group = "KafkaConsumerBatch"

  val prot = new Properties()
  prot.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  prot.put("group.id",consumer_group)
  prot.put("key.deserializer",  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  prot.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

  val kfk_consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String,String](prot)
  kfk_consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singleton(topic_name))
  println("here")

   while(true){
    val consumer_record : ConsumerRecords[String, String]  = kfk_consumer.poll(100)
    println("records count : " + consumer_record.count())
    println("records partitions: " + consumer_record.partitions())
    consumer_record.iterator().


  }

}
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Have you tried something like `for (record <- consumer_record.iterator()){ // do stuff with record }` ?

Comment: ya. i tried different ways. everytime getting compile error : 

Error:(29, 44) value foreach is not a member of java.util.Iterator[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]]
     for(record <- consumer_record.iterator())
                                           ^

Comment: Add `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Comment: even bad luck, already tried.

Comment: This is working for me: https://gist.github.com/mfirry/27987bd197c329f5bfbfb5a34c46b588

Comment: @mfirry : Yes . you are correct.  by Add import scala.collection.JavaConversions._  , some extra method are appear. like key(), value()... Thank you.

Comment: Moving this from comment to answer, so it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do that

```
for (record <- consumer_record.iterator()) {
  println(s"Here's your $record")
}
```

Remember to add this import:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another answer since the `scala.collection.JavaConversions` was deprecated as mentioned at [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html).

As for this question, the code could be like

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

for (record <- asScalaIterator(consumer_record.iterator)) {
  println(s"Here's your $record")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true){
    val consumer_records = kfk_consumer.poll(100)
    val record_iter=consumer_record.iterator()
    while(record_iter.hasNext())
    {
       record=record_iter.next()
       println("records partitions: " + record.partition()
               "records_data:" + record.value())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you offer some explanation? What are you doing here? How does this differ from the accepted answer, and why do you prefer this approach?